# JIRA: Agile: adding jira issues directly to a sprint

Tags: agile

When looking at the Plan view of a scrum RapidBoard, is it possible to add issues directly to a sprint? There is a link against the Epics for adding directly to an Epic.

Comment: I did file a ticket with Atlassian. Otherwise, if you know the sprint numbers, editing the field directly works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You may enter the Sprint Id the in the 'Sprint' field while creating the ticket -> (this is kind of pain as you need to know the id of the Sprint and not the name)
- [Update] - You cannot create a ticket directly in the current Sprint (at least the way my JIRA is configured) except by adding the Sprint Id.  When I had one of the tickets in the current Sprint selected, and I created a new ticket, it does, however, place the newly created ticket at the top of the backlog.  At least, this makes it easier to just pull in the current Sprint

Answer (score 0):

After the creation of the issue you can use the Send to option by right clicking on the issue. This allows you to send the issue to any sprint of your board.